# Simple Mouseover not Working in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mouseover

Okay, so I am working on a game-center.  I got this cool idea so when I mouseover a hyperlink it shows a scary face (just for kickz & gigglez);

The problem is, it works perfectly in Firefox, but not Google Chrome?  The demo is over here:

http://bouncygames.org/games/scary/

Please help... :(

**My Question: ** *How come this is not working in Chrome, and how can I fix this?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any javascript whatsoever, just use this css-declaration and it will work perfectly in all browsers:

```
#img{
   display:none;
}

a:hover ~ #img{
   display:block;
}
```

To make it more specific (so that it will not trigger on all hovered anchors), put a class onto your anchor and write ( e.g. `.scary:hover ~ #img` ).

Don't use onmouseover and onmouseout these are considered bad coding practice for several reasons.
Also, don't use the `center` tag, but use the css-declaration `text-align:center` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your script, instead of using img.style.visibility, use

```
img.style.display="none";
```

and

```
img.style.display="block";
```

make sure you also remove the visibility='hidden' attribute from your img tag or it won't work

There is a space between getElementById and ('img'), remove that and try again.

Comment: it should be 'none', not 'hidden' :)

Comment: Not working.  Now the image shows in the start and it's all messed up..?

Comment: There is a space between getElementById and ('img'), remove that and try again.

Comment: No problem, Christoph suggestions are the way to go for sure, but I was trying to find I out what was wrong with your code exactly (other than being not very elegant :))